Can Fubini's theorem be applied to this function defined on $[0,1]^2$?
During my real analysis (measure theory) course, we encountered the following problem: Consider the function $f(x, y)$ defined on $[0,1]^2$ as follows for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$f(x, y) =
\begin{cases} 
2^{2n} + 2^{-n}, & \text{if } (x, y) \in [2^{-n}, 2^{1-n}]^2, \\
-2^{2n+1}, & \text{if } (x, y) \in [2^{-n}, 2^{1-n}] \times [2^{-n-1}, 2^{-n}], \\
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$
I attempted to verify whether Fubini's theorem can be applied to $f(x, y)$. My trial involves computing the double integral.
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x, y) \, dx \, dy &= \int_{1/2^n}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left( 2^{2n} + 2^{-n} \right) \, dx \, dy 
+ \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left( -2^{2n+1} \right) \, dx \, dy \\ 
&= \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left( 2^{2n+1} + 2^{1-n} \right) \, dx \, dy 
- \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} \left( 2^{2n+1} \right) \, dx \, dy \\ 
&= \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} 2^{1-n} \, dx \, dy \\ 
&= 2^{1-n}\left[ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^n} \right] \left[ \frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right] \\ 
&= \frac{2^{1-n}}{2} \left( \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} - \frac{1}{2^n} \right)^2 \\ 
&= \frac{2^{1-n}}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \left[ \frac{1}{2^{-1}} - 1 \right]^2 \\ 
&= \frac{1}{2^{3n}}.
\end{align*}
I would really appreciate if anyone could kindly clarify whether or not the Fubini theorem be applied to this function?

What are the conditions of Fubini's theorem, and why can you not check if they're satisfied? I think adding this context may help us help you. (The first part of the question is somewhat rhetorical, I know what they are, but it might help you to write them down so as to potentially "demystify" the theorem and see what you actually have to show to apply the theorem.)

For any two measure spaces $(X, A, \mu)$ and $(Y, B, \nu)$, with $\nu$ complete. If f is integrable over $X \times Y$ with respect to the product measure $\mu \times \nu$, then for almost all $x \in X$, the $x$-section of $f$ $f(x, \cdot)$ is integrable over $Y$ with respect to $\nu$ and
$\int_{X \times Y} f d(\mu \times \nu) = \int_X \left(\int_Y f(x, y) d\nu(y)\right)d\mu(x)$.
This is what I read in the recommended text, Royden. I would appreciate if you could help in demystifying it in relation to the problem.

There are a number of places where I am confused.
Clearly, $f$ is not nonnegative, but the integral seems to be finite. However, there seems to be a problem with the function as $f(x, 2^{-n}) = 2^{2n} + 2^{-n}$ and $-2^{2n+1}$ for $x \in [2^{-n}, 2^{-n+1}]$, so one input has more than one value, which I believe means the function may not be well-defined.

Remember that "integrability" always refers to whether or not the integral of $|f|$, not $f$, is finite. There exist functions for which an integral may exist in the generalised Riemann sense but not in the Lebesgue sense, so to check integrability you should always take the absolute value. It's also somewhat fine if the function is badly defined on zero-measure sets like a countable number of points, because that will not affect the equivalence class and thus the integral, although I do agree that this particular $f$ is not well-defined at the points you mentioned.

What you wrote is also something that you should instead put in the body of your question, because I think that with this context your question should be more well-received.

Thank you for the comments. Could you kindly arrive at a conclusion for me? Does Fubini theorem hold for that function or not? Also, in Royden, it is mentioned that a \textbf{nonnegative} function is said to be integrable, if the integral of $|f|$ is finite. This was why I wrote about the sign of $f$.

Oh, I should have asked beforehand since both of the answers on this question use different interpretations, but it supposed to be a function $f = f_n$ with only three different values, or was it supposed to be like in John's answer?

I believe that the Fubini theorem can not be applied to this function.
My attempt:
The function $f(x,y)$ is defined piecewise, sometimes being positive on the squares and rectangles recorded in $[0,1]^2$. What is vital is to judge its magnitude of integrability.
The integral of $|f(x,y)|$ over $[0,1]^2$ is then calculated by adding together the integrals over the particular squares and rectangles:
$$ \iint_{[0,1]^2} |f(x,y)| \, dx \, dy = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{1-n}} \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{1-n}} (2^{2n}+2^{-n}) dx dy + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2^{-n-1}}^{2^{-n}} \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{1-n}} 2^{2n+1} dx dy $$
The definite mathematical operations lead us to:
$$ \iint_{[0,1]^2} |f(x,y)| \, dx \, dy= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (2 + 2^{-3n}) $$
The series is then divergent.  The integral $\iint_{[0,1]^2} |f(x,y)| \, dx \, dy = \infty$, which implies that $f$ is not absolutely integrable.
Fubini's theorem is valid only under the condition that there is absolute integrability which assures that the iterated integrals are equal to the double integral. Since $f$ does not satisfy this condition, Fubini's theorem cannot be used to reverse the order of integration in this case. Although the outcome the $∫$.

EDIT: My answer used the interpretation that felt natural looking at OP's calculation, i.e. $f$ is a function depending on $n$ with only three values. John's answer is more appropriate if the correct interpretation was that $f$ is a single function with a countable number of values determined by which rectangle the pair $(x,y)$ is located in.
In this context, you can just directly compute $\iint_{[0,1]^2} |f(x,y)| \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ and see if it is finite, which you can apply Fubini-Tonelli on to swap integrals regardless of whether the joint integral is finite or not since the integrand is now positive, so that it is almost the same calculation you've already done.
Otherwise, in more general settings, what you want to do is "simply" show that $f$ is $L^1([0,1] \times [0,1])$, especially since measurability is almost always a given. As far as completeness goes, remember that the Lebesgue measure is complete, so that it is pretty much a non-issue in "standard" situations like this one.
For example, here, even faster than computing the inetgral of the absolute value is noticing that your function $f$ is bounded over a set of finite measure, thus integrable if it is measurable, and it is measurable since it is a simple function.
